# Div slidingUp and slidingDown issues

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown, slideup

I am jquery slideUp and slideDown property. There are two divs I am using for two href links. onclick of login ans signup button the corresponding divs should slide up and slide down. but while clicking on signup button its sliding up over the login box before the sliding of login box and vice versa. Can anyone help me how to avoid this sliding of one div on another one.

the following is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            body
            {
                background-color:#000;
            }
            #container
            {
                margin-top:10%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                <!--margin-right: 200px;-->
                border-style: none;
                width:350px;
            }
            #tabbox
            {
                height:40px;
                border-style:none;
            }
            #panel
            {
                height:300px;
                border-style:none;
                background-color:#FFF;
                border-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow:8px 8px 5px #B8B894;
            }
            .tab
            {
                background:#dedede;
                display:block;
                height:40px;
                line-height:40px;
                text-align:center;
                width: 80px;
                float: right;
                font-weight:bold;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
            }
            a
            {
                color: #000;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .signup
            {
                margin-left:8px;
                margin-right:7px;
                <!--box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px #888888;-->
            }
            .select
            {
                background-color:#EBFFF5;
                <!--box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px #888888;#CCE680-->
            }
            #loginbox
            {
                min-height:200px;
                margin-left:30px;
                padding:10px;
                padding-top:70px;
            }
            #signupbox
            {
                display:none;
                min-height:200px;
                padding:5px;
                margin-left:30px;
                padding-top:90px;
            }
            #loginEmail
            {
                background-image:url('user.png');
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                padding-left:30px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border-color: #668566;
                box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #888888;
                height:25px;
                width:70%;
            }
            #loginPwd
            {
                background-image:url('key1.png');
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                padding-left:30px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border-color: #668566;
                box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #888888;
                height:25px;
                width:70%;
            }
            #submit
            {
                height:30px;
                width:30%;
                box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #888888;
                border-radius: 9px;
                background-color: #99D6AD;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            p 
            {
                font-family: "Times New Roman", Times;
                font-size:30px;
            }
            #signupemail
            {
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                padding-left:30px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border-color: #668566;
                box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #888888;
                height:25px;
                width:70%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".tab").click(function()
            {
                var X=$(this).attr('id');
                if(X=='login')
                {
                $("#signup").removeClass('select');
                $("#login").addClass('select');
                $("#signupbox").slideUp();
                $("#loginbox").slideDown();

                }
                else
                {
                $("#login").removeClass('select');
                $("#signup").addClass('select');
                $("#signupbox").slideDown();
                $("#loginbox").slideUp();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="tabbox">
                <a href="#" id="signup" class="tab signup">SignUp<a>
                <a href="#" id="login" class="tab select">Login<a>
            </div>

            <div id="panel">
                <div id="loginbox">
                    <br>
                    <input type="email" name="loginEmail" id="loginEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="loginPwd" id="loginPwd" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
                </div>

                <div id="signupbox">
                    <input type="email" name="loginEmail" id="signupemail" placeholder="Enter Email"/>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Mail">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html
```

Comment: use call back method to slide-down and slide-up jquery method.
check this URL  http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

Comment: Its coming properly. I used show and hide property instead of slide up and slide down

Comment: so its solve your problem??

Comment: ok great. callback function also solve your issue using slideup/sldiedown

Comment: Ya it got solved.. Thank you for your help..